# git branch switching and submodules

Tags: git

I have 2 branch, `master` & `secondary` and they're kept in sync periodically by merging `master => secondary.`

At one point, `master` had a several submodules that were deleted and the same submodules were re-added.

I'm now trying to merge `master` into `secondary` but whenever I try to switch from `master` to `secondary`, I get these error messages on the submodules that were overwritten:

```
warning: unable to rmdir libs/AFNetworking: Directory not empty
warning: unable to rmdir libs/MBProgressHUD: Directory not empty
Branch secondary set up to track remote branch secondary from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'secondary'
```

'master' branch starts like this:

```
git clone repourl:master.git
cd project_directory
git submodule update --init <= in master at the moment
git checkout secondary
```

Comment: I'm not sure but it sounds like those directories where undet git in one branch but they arent in the other branch.

Comment: how can I tell which branch they're not part of?